# Overwrite default values from source table using union

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table, I have few specific keys and few generic keys. Specific data can be got by combining specific key column values on top of generic key column values.

```
Specific key  | Generic key   | Col1        | Col2          |

Null          | generic key 1 | defaultVal1 | default Val2  |
Specific key1 | generic key 1 | Null        | Specific val2 |
```

In this case my specific record should need to look like,

```
Specific key1 | generic key 1 | defaultVal1 | Specific val2|
```

I am trying to achieve this using union statement, but, it is overwriting the Null value for Specific key1 on top of generic defaultVal1.

Hence I would like to get columns overwritten on top of generic records when it is not null. If the columns of specific record is null, then I want to retain the default value.

**EDIT:**

I tried to provide info as simple as possible, looks like it attracts more downvotes. Here I am trying to explain my schema bit further:

I have 2 tables namely ids_link, core_params

ids_link table contents:

Unique key : specificid

### | globalid | specificid | type |

| gid1 | sid1 | type1 |

| gid1 | sid2 | type2 |

| gid2 | sid3 | type1 |

| gid2 | sid4 | type2 |

| gid3 | sid5 | type1 |

core_params table :
Uniquekey : id

### | id | coreparam1 | coreparam2 |

| gid1 | defaultVal1 | defaultVal2 |

| sid1 | NULL | sid1Val2 |

| sid2 | sid2val1 | NULL |

| sid3 | sid3val1 | NULL |

In short, more than one specific id share a global id. The global ID will have default values for its corresponding specific ids. The specific id will have specific content that needs to be overwritten on top of its corresponding global id values and returned.
For example)
If I want to return all the specific records for type 1, then my output will be,

### | specificid | globalid | type | coreparam1 | coreparam2 |

| sid1 | gid1 | type1 | defaultVal1 | sid1val2 |

| sid3 | gid2 | type1 | sid3val1 | NULL |

If you would have noticed here, for sid1, in core_params table, there is no value for coreparam1. But it is backfilled using the default value from the gid1 record.
For sid3, there is no default record to backfill for coreparam2. Hence it coreparams2 field stays null. I am trying to write a sql query to achieve this. The query I tried :

```
select specificid,globalid,type,coreparam1,coreparam2 from ids_link left join core_params on ids_link.globalid=coreparams.id where type='type1' union all select specificid,globalid,type,coreparam1,coreparam2 from ids_link left join core_params on ids_link.specificid=coreparams.id where type='type1' LIMIT 10;
```

But in this, if there are NULL values for records in core_params table for specifickeys like for sid1, coreparam1 column is null, I want that to be backfilled with that of its global value (defaultVal1). Kindly let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL you have so far?

Comment: Your example is very short. What is the primary key of the table?  Or first column is just two values `NULL` and `specific key 1 `How you know what is a default val2 or a specific val2? what is the diference?

Comment: I have provided more info. Kindly check that and mention if some points are not clear

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help to re-create your scenario.

-- Create test table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Col1] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Col2] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Col3] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Col4] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
)
```

--Insert test rows

```
insert into Test Values (Null, 'Generic Key 1', 'dfaultVal1', 'DefaultVal2')
insert into Test Values ('Specific Key 1', 'Generic Key 1', Null, 'Specific Val 2')
```

You said that u use Specific Key in combination with Generic Key, if this is true you will not reach defaultval1 on Col1, so maybe you need to elaborate better. You could try to work with min/max or criteria like Like and keep selecting subsets till you filter the way you wanted.

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4 
from test t, 
     (select max(col1) good1, max(col2) good2 from test) goodkey 
     where t.col1 = goodkey.good1 and t.col2 = goodkey.good2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MCoelho. Your suggestion is really helpful. I updated my question with more info. I am using joins between tables to achieve this as well. In my tables, I have few boolean columns for specific records and global records. In this case, max() might not work good as if my specific record contains value as false, it will be overwritten by generic record with value as true. In this case, instead of max() is there some other function like NOT NULL (col1)? I again appreciate your time and effort for answering my question.

Comment: Also apart from boolean fields, even the text fields could be present for both specific record and global record. Hence in this case, max() function or even not null ()  will not address the concern as specific record's fields should be given higher priority over global record's fields if specific record's field is not null.